# Drawing a plot using System.Drawing Only

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, graph, system.drawing

In my application in Windows Phone, i have made a custom plotting library for some simple plotting of a graph. I did this, using `System.Windows.Shapes`. Now i run to some problems when i want to use this on other platforms (android, and iphone, using mono).

So i came to the conclusion that i may need to remake te library using `System.Drawing` only. Because that namespace is available on all three platforms, and (if i have googled correctly) contains some functionally in drawing stuff on ui's.

My Questions

1. Am i correct in the fact that drawing contains drawing functions.. If so, how do i make a multi point line or polyLine?
2. Are there any (allready available) libraries that do the same using the System.Drawing namespace only?
3. If there are any plotting libraries that are available for only Android an MonoTouch than that will do aswell, because i've allready got a graph drawing function on my windowsphone, This will be my last resort. Because i want to keep the code behind the platforms mostly the same.

Comment: you may want to take a look at Frank Krueger's CrossGraphics library: https://github.com/praeclarum/CrossGraphics

Comment: have done that, and it works (atleast for the draw functions on the three platforms)

Answer (score 0):

What i found out:

After some time put in to searching for an answer for this, i gave op hope to find libraries that implement a graph functionality for all the three platforms. There just doesn't seem to be one. There are libraries available for Silverlight and Monotouch(IOS) but, the silverlight part is NOT compatible with windows phone.

I found out that the library `system.drawing` does not have full functionality in silverlight, so after some careful consideration I also stepped away from that idea. And Moved towards making my own library that implements some `#if (SILVERLIGHT)` or `#if (MONOTOUCH)` region functionality.

At this point i have made my own library for WindowsPhone being able to draw a decent plain and simple graph. I eventualy done this using the `System.Windows.Shapes` namespace. Today i will start making the same sort of lib for android. And after that i will do it for windowsphone, The library will be open source, and when finished i think i will release it somewhere.

> As a sort of summary: "there was not a real answer to my question, so
>   i had to work around it. This work around made me make my own cross
>   platform library
>   ".